# Form in html is not able to submit data when clicked on submit button?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have made a from to get contact details of user and store it in local storage. When I click on `Submit` button it does not submit it and `submittoDB()` function is not getting fired why is this happening ?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12" id="addNewContact">
     <form>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Name:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nameInput" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="number">Number:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="numberInput" required>
      </div> 
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="group">Group:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="groupInput" required>
      </div> 
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" onsubmit="submitToDb()">Submit</button>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have also used `required` in each input.

Comment: send your JavaScript and any dynamic code if neccessary

Comment: Your form does not have an `action` or a `method` specified for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `onsubmit` for the button, you need to move it to the form:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12" id="addNewContact">
     <form onsubmit="submitToDb()">
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Name:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nameInput" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="number">Number:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="numberInput" required>
      </div> 
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="group">Group:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="groupInput" required>
      </div> 
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

onsubmit must be in the form tag

Here an example from w3schools

```js
function myFunction() {
    alert("The form was submitted");
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="myFunction()">
  Enter name: <input type="text" name="fname" required>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Here is the link to the example:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onsubmit.asp